# How to query and retrieve results from ~100 customer databases using SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jdbc, dao

I have the scenario where I have to run 10 different queries on 100 customer databases with similar structure and then push the results to an ElasticSearch cluster for analysis. All the database connections are configured inside my applications.properties file. I decided to use Spring-Boot for the project and Java High Level Rest Client as the ElasticSearch API. However I found that in Spring-Boot I have to create an entity class for every entity and create a separate class and methods for each database connection. I am new to Spring Boot and am also not understanding the concepts of entitymanager or rowmapper. It is quite different from Java connection-statement-query-resultset format. Kindly help me

I have tried creating this Database configuration class where I tried to configure a single database reading from the properties file. I have created the basic datasource() and jdbctemplate() methods

```
package elasticsearch;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = { "elasticsearch" }
)
public class DatabaseConfig {


@Bean(name = "dataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "primary.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}


@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource         dataSource){
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}


@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("elasticsearch")
            .persistenceUnit("elasticsearch")
            .build();
}


@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                entityManagerFactory
) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

}

I do not want to create an entity class for every object because the queries and also the results can vary. Also I do not want to create rowmappers because I have already written Json mappers for the rows retrieved to push it to elasticsearch

Comment: You could also not use JPA, and use plain JDBC (or maybe jOOQ). In that case you don't need to define entities.

Comment: Does plain JDBC work with Spring Boot? So in that case I do not have to create repositories or controllers right?

Comment: Of course plain JDBC works with Spring Boot. JPA **uses** JDBC itself.

Comment: Thanks for this input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to Spring Boot and am also not understanding the concepts of
>   entitymanager or rowmapper.

You don't show any of the details of your schema, but I don't think you need both JPA and `JdbcTemplate`.  I'd recommend one or the other.

My preference would be `JdbcTemplate`.

JPA/Hibernate is overkill and complexity that you don't need.   `JdbcTemplate` will be fine if you are comfortable with writing SQL SELECTs.

> It is quite different from Java connection-statement-query-resultset format.

Not really.  `JdbcTemplate` helps you with the boilerplate, but it's still JDBC underneath.

100 client databases will require 100 sets of URL and credentials, one for each.  That is a *lot* of configuration.  You can't get around that.

The problem is intractable if the schemas are not identical for all customers.

I would separate the two problems: querying for customer data and pushing to Elastic Search.

You only need a single `RowMapper` per query if the schema and query are identical for all customers.

I think a single repository/data access object can be used.  You only need write and test it once, but you need to instantiate a new instance at runtime for each database connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. The properties file is quite sensitive in this case and so I thought of creating abstraction layers instead of plain reading the file and running the JDBC connection with those values using explicit names. The whole SpringBoot idea is there to run it as a microservice. I guess normal JDBC or JdbcTemplate works here

Comment: Feels less like a microservice to me and more like a batch job you'd want to run periodically to get updates.  You don't need every new technology for this problem.  Choose wisely.

Comment: "Sensitive"?  How so?  This sounds like a straightforward problem: (1) Read N sets of connection configuration sets, (2) loop over each connection, (3) loop over each query to be executed per customer, (4) query for the collection of data you require, (5) push the collection of data to Elastic Search.  Do it for one customer, see that the performance is like, decide if this process can fit into your batch window.

Comment: Yes you have identified it correctly, it will be a batch job running periodically. The only thing is I can never mention any customer name or details inside my code, that has to be done differently. Hence I was thinking of using abstraction layers etc. But I think now I have an idea reading your initial take on the problem. Thanks again

Comment: Abstraction?  An interface with encrypted credentials and a guid per customer will do it.